# Check to see if an Ansible Prompt Variable exists

Tags: if-statement, ansible, prompt, exists

In my site.yml, I run some common tasks, then include 3 other playbooks.
These 3 playbooks then run a role each.
I do this so I can run a full site.yml install, or I can just run a smaller playbook.

I want to prompt for a username and password in the site.yml, which I can do.
Then in the other 3 playbooks/roles, I want to check if the username and password were already created, if not, then prompt for them.

I do not want to prompt for credentials multiple times.

**site.yml**

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "username"
    - prompt" "enter username"

- include: 1.yml
```

**1.yml**

```
---
- name: install one
  hosts: all

  # If username has not been defined - This is 
  # where I am confused how to check if it was defined in site.yml
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "userame"
      prompt: "enter username"
  roles:
    - 1role
```

If I run site.yml, it will get username, then run 1.yml and I don't want it to prompt for username because it was prompted for in site.yml.

If I run just 1.yml, I want it to prompt for the username, as I am not running site.yml in this case.

Is there a way to prompt for credentials from a playbook, then check for them in an included playbook?

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html

Answer (score 0):

You should make a file that ansible writes on host and ansible could then check whether those credentials have been filled in or not yet, or you could use register (probably the best option) and then use when to check (when is like an if statement)

For instance:

**site.yml**

```
- name: "username"
- prompt" "enter username"  
  register: username_check
```

**1.yml**

```
- name: "userame"
  prompt: "enter username"  
  when: username_check is not defined
```

I hope this helps in some regard. I tried to comment but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: using Register did not work.  I was prompted in site.yml, then again in 1.yml.  I'll try to check first, write a file, then check for file.  I am not fond of that method.

Comment: I guess that makes sense that register doesn't work, since they are different playbooks. If there is an easier way to transfer a variable as true or false (that was what I was thinking with the file method).